# Android: java method type API level 25, cause issue if not called?

Tags: java, android, datasource

This class is shared between java and android.

```
public class Foo {
    ....
    javax.sql.DataSource getDataSource() {
        ....
    }


}
```

The DataSource class on android requires API level 25. But the method getDataSource() will not be called on android. Will this cause problem on android with API level < 25?

Answer (score 0):

This will not make any error on compiling time. So in my opinion if you never use it, it won't cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

Erase never called code, but no, there's no RuntimeExceptions if you DON'T call newer API codes trough code.

Please note, that when implementing interfaces the API may try to use the methods for you.